# Байтовая последовательность декодируется в символы некорректно

Tags: python

Есть такой пример, где мы сначала кодируем последовательность, а потом декодируем. Но в данном случае на выходе получается не ожидаемое 'A я', а разные результаты (в зависимости от кодировки) не один из который не верный. Подскажите, как поправить?

```
secret='A я'

bit_list = ''
byte_array = []


for byte in secret.encode('cp1251'):
    print(byte)
    for bit in bin(byte)[2:].zfill(8):
        bit_list += bit

        if len(bit_list) == 8:
            byte = int(bit_list, 2)
            print(byte)

            byte_array.append(byte)
            bit_list = ''

print(byte_array)


for byte in byte_array:
    print(str(chr(byte)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, потому что ваша строка неверно декодируется. Проблемы, как я понимаю, возникают со строчной буквой 'я'.Так вот она у вас U+044F

```
print(ord('я')) # 1103
```

В cp1251 'я' имеет код 255, что неверно интерпретируется функцией chr, например так (cp1252) :

```
chr(255) -> 'ÿ'
```

Поэтому я бы советовал делать явный декодинг:

```
secret="A я"
a = bytearray()
b = bytearray()
a.extend(secret.encode('utf8'))
b.extend(secret.encode('cp1251'))
print(a)
print(b)
print(a.decode('utf8'))
print(b.decode('cp1251'))
```

На выходе:

```
bytearray(b'A \xd1\x8f')
bytearray(b'A \xff')
A я
A я
```

И вообще, мне непонятно, зачем вы делаете цикл с заполнением byte_array, если вы уже получили этот байт в `for byte in secret.encode('cp1251')`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!